# Starting Ubuntu gives no screen on external graphics and no GUI on internal

Tags: boot, nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu 14 using Unetbootin on one of my harddrives (I have windows 7 and want Ubuntu to dual boot). When I started the installation of Ubuntu the screen went blank and got no video signal. I thought that this was because I was running on my external graphics card so I opened BIOS and changed graphics card to the integrated one and everything worked fine.

The problem is that when i start Ubuntu with my external graphics card activated, I get the same as in Unetbootin - no signal. If I start it with my internal graphics I get signal but it takes me to the terminal instead of the GUI. if i run `startx` it says

```
xauth: file /home/user/.Xauthority does not exist
```

at the top and the following at the bottom:

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

My external graphics card is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate the external NVIDIA graphics, then install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Note : 
In case it does not work with `nouveau.modeset=0` - try it again with `nomodeset`.
In case it still does not work, install the drivers with activated internal card and activate
the dedicated NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 970 graphics adapter after the installation in BIOS.

Comment: starting on my internal GPU and installing the drivers worked!